# PHP char type encryption

Tags: php, variables, char

While finishing my websites java login program and page, I decided to pass an encypted value through the URL to a validation page as an extra line of security. I have an encyrption algorithim that I wrote long ago that no one I know has cracked yet so I want to use that. But I need chars for it to properly work. From what I can tell, PHP doesn't have a char type. So my question is first, is their a char type, and secondly, is it possible to convert that to an int? Side Note: Login is a signed applet so all pages are in PHP. Edit: Forgot to mention that this is just the base of encryption and I will be adding to the algorithim.

Comment: "I have an encyrption algorithim that ... no one I know has cracked yet" Don't roll your own security.

Comment: If you want to test how secure it is, then get somebody else to try and crack it. If they can't, then that says something good about your algorithm.

Comment: I had my teacher and everyone in my programming class test it when I first wrote it. They couldn't. Then I asked the best student in the class one year later to try again. He still couldn't. Is that good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference a character in a string `$str` by `$str[$index]`.

The `ord` function will return a character's integer value:

```
$val = ord($str[$index]);
```

The `chr` function does the opposite:

```
$char = chr($val);//$char == $str[$index]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This will work out for the first part, but can I change it to an int, i.e.
`$val = (int) ord($str[$index]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can access a string `$s` character by character by referring to `$s[$i]`. `ord($s)` gets the ASCII value of a character, `chr($n)` gets the character corresponding to an ASCII value.

**Don't use your own cryptographic primitives** unless you know what you are doing! Use PHP's own implementations of known strong algorithms (e.g. AES-256). Just because no one *you* know has cracked your custom algorithm doesn't mean someone else can't.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `char` type in PHP, and the `string` type does not readily convert to `int`. PHP handles dynamic type-juggling, so type declarations are not used.

On a side note, "no one has cracked [my encryption algorithm] yet" doesn't necessarily mean someone won't in the future. If you're encrypting important stuff, use the standard encryption algorithms - they're standard for a reason.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that this is just the base of the encryption. I decided quickly to encrypt it even further. I will edit that right now.